# Firefox-ESR won't load any pages (i.e. shows blank pages)

Tags: linux, kali-linux, firefox

**OS : Kali Linux 2020.4**

**Mozilla Firefox 78.9.0esr**

So I recently faced an error regarding videos not playing on YouTube with my Firefox-ESR (default browser in Kali), so I tried to fix it by uninstalling and re-installing Firefox-ESR using the reference links respectively [uninstalling](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16758/removing-firefox-in-ubuntu-with-all-add-ons-like-it-never-existed) and `sudo apt-get install firefox-esr`

#### Problem

Whenever I run Firefox-ESR either from terminal or from the Kali menu and try to go to a website
the website doesn't load and all I have is a blank page with nothing on it (it doesn't even indicate that if it's loading something.)

[image: This is what I see when I try to go to any website]

#### Methods That I Tried

1. Deleting Cache, History, Cookies..
2. Uninstalling/Re-installing
3. Running it with it's addons disabled. (safe mode)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with Firefox-esr 78.12.0
I found this Bugticket: "Debian Bug report logs - #981184" https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=981184
but the hint to update libnss3 did not work for me.

Firefox only loads a page when I disable all add-ons

Comment: Today i noticed that the Add-on "uMatrix" was not up to date. After updateing it, my firefox is working as expected.